# Simple Question about stsadm -o migrateuser cmdlet

Tags: 2007, active-directory, user-accounts, stsadm

Just for my clarification i want to ask a simple question:

I per my understanding, stsadm -o migrateuser command will only migrate the userAccounts if the userAccounts exists on both Active directories, right?

For example, if i want to migrate a user xyz from DomainA\xyz to DomainB\xyz, then user xyz should exist in both DomainA and DomainB before i run stsadm -o migrate command, is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Your understanding is correct.

When you run the migrateuser command if new login does not exist in AD then this command will throw the errors. It will copy the permission from old ID to new ID.

Answer (score 1):

The `migrateuse` STSADM operation actually associates the existing permissions of `DomainA\xyz`(Old user) with `DomainB\xyz`(New user). In this process it first removes all the existing permissions of `DomainB\xyz` (New user), if any.

[Here](http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=75) is a very good detailed explanation of how actually `migrateuser` operation is executed behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

`Migrate` command Migrates a user account in Windows SharePoint Services 3.0 to a new login name and binary ID. If an entry for the new login name already exists, the entry is marked for deletion to make way for the migration. Migrates user access from one domain user to another.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288467(v=office.12).aspx